# Override function in multiple classes that all have a same superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I'm using some third party library in Java, the source code is not available, right now I want to inherit some of the classes(all single inheritance, in terms of mapping them to my version classes) and override one function within them. I realize that this function is a default function which gets inherited from an ancestor object. The inheritance hierarchy is known and quite complicated, I know that if I have the source code it would be easy to achieve my goal, however is it still possible to do it without manually overriding it in every subclass i made, which will generate a lot of duplicated code?

Comment: You can minimize the duplicated code by moving the implementation of the method somewhere common: `@Override void theMethod(){ CommonLib.doItOverHere(this); }`

Answer (score 0):

You should create an abstract class with all needed implementation that would inherit from the third party library class and from that abstract class create the sub classes you need.